# Quit Word.Application which opened in the child subrotine

Tags: excel, ms-word, vba

**We declared `Word.Application` object in the `Pro1` child function below. As we need return the `Word.Document` object, that should be remained opened. How can I do quit the Word application in the parent SubRoutuine(`test01`)**

---

**I need the `objWord` object which declared in `Pro1` function will quit -quietly without prompt- after the `test01` procedure running have end.**

I have two procedure below

And perform this:

```
Sub test01()
    WrdPDF objDoc:=Pro1 strPath:=ThisWorkbook.path & "\" & "rep.pdf"
End Sub
```

|

```
Function Pro1 As Word.Document

    'Declaration
    Dim objWord As Word.Application
    ' Here we declare a Word Application in the function and need 
    ' quit that in another procedure (The parent one which is test01). 
    Dim objDocTotal As Word.Document
    Dim objDoc As Word.Document

    'Initializing
    Worksheets("Salary").OLEObjects("PayCheck").Activate
    Set objWord = GetObject(, "Word.Application")
    objWord.Visible = False
    Set objDoc = objWord.ActiveDocument
    Set objDocTotal = objWord.Documents.Add

...

    Proc1 = objDocTotal
End Function
```

|

```
Sub WrdPDF(objDoc As Object, strPath As String, Optional Opn As Boolean) 'MS-Word PDF
    objDoc.ExportAsFixedFormat _
        outputfileName:=strPath _
        , exportformat:=wdExportFormatPDF _
        , openafterexport:=Opn _
        , optimizefor:=wdExportOptimizeForPrint _
        , Range:=wdExportAllDocument _
        , Item:=wdExportDocumentContent _
        , includedocprops:=False _
        , keepirm:=True _
        , createbookmarks:=wdExportCreateNoBookmarks _
        , docstructuretags:=True _
        , bitmapmissingfonts:=True _
        , useiso19005_1:=False
End Sub
```

Regards.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't Quit in that sub-routine and leave a document open. Once that subroutine ends, the variable objWord is no longer available - you've "orphaned" the instance of Word.

I see two possibilities, right off-hand, both of which involve passing and getting an object back from `Proc1` so that you can access the application object:

1) You can declare the Word.Application object in test_01 and pass it to Proc1

```
Sub test01()
    Dim objWord as Word.Application
    WrdPDF objDoc:=Proc1(objWord), strPath:=ThisWorkbook.path & "\" & "rep.pdf"
    objWord.Quit 0
End Sub

Function Proc1(ref objWord as Word.Application) As Word.Document
    Dim objDocTotal As Word.Document
    Dim objDoc As Word.Document
    'And so on, as you currently have, without declaring objWord here
```

2) You can use access the application object via the document object returned by your Proc1:

```
Sub test01()
    Dim objDoc as Word.Document
    Dim objWord as Word.Application
    Dim strPath as String

    strPath = ThisWorkbook.path & "\" & "rep.pdf"
    Set objDoc = Proc1
    WrdPDF objDoc, strPath
    Set objWord = objDoc.Application
    objWord.Quit 0 'do not prompt to save changes
End Sub
```

I'd probably tend to use (2), but both work when I test them.

Comment: I used second approach.